# How to prevent java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.sql.types when running in DataBricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql

When I run the spark application from *IDE* , it compiles and runs fine. However when I package the jar to run in cloud, by setting the Spark dependency scope to "`provided`", and run the jar in cloud (with same version of Spark), I get "`java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType`".

I have made sure that all Spark dependencies are set to provided scope. I am using *Spark 2.4.1* , the same as the Spark version of the cluster in cloud. How to further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Have you added the spark sql dependencies as well? If so can you see if the fat jar has them

Comment: I have set all spark dependencies as " provided " in the POM file, as I am trying to execute it on Azure DataBricks cloud and the environment provides the spark modules.